# Oracle Apex - pl/sql returning a sql query

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Apex 4.0 I'm creating a report using SQL [PL/SQL Function body returning SQL Query] and I've got some simple as a test

```
DECLARE
v_test varchar(20): = 'Select * from <mytable>';
BEGIN
return v_test;
END;
```

This displays the report with the correct information, however can I now pass the variable v_test to other objects on the same page? I've tried creating a item that has a name of v_test and using various different source options to see if it lists this variable but I've yet to figure out how to get it to display what this variable v_test

Comment: The variable `v_test` is local (private) to the function, so no it cannot be referred anywhere else. Your code could (perhaps) put the value in a page item if the query is <4000 characters, e.g. `apex_util.set_session_state('P1_MY_QUERY',v_test);`